# How to display header template and item template in repeater?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, vb.net

I want to display repeater in web page. In repeater i have header template and item template to be displayed in vb.net
And I have a add button below to that repeater, when i click on that i should get a new empty row below to that repeater. Please help me with this. 
Repeater:

```
        <HeaderTemplate>
            <table id="tblProductDetails" runat="server" class="tableStyle" border="1">
                <tr class="tableStyle">
                    <td id="td1" class="align-center tableStyle" style="height: 50px;">
                        <div class="grid-2">
                            <strong>
                                <asp:Label ID="lblNumber" Width="10px" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label></strong>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                    <td id="td2" class="align-center tableStyle" style="height: 50px;">
                        <div class="grid-6">
                            <strong>
                                <asp:Label ID="lblCompany" runat="server" Text="Company"></asp:Label></strong><span class="required">*</span>
                        </div>
                    </td>

                    <td id="td3" class="align-center tableStyle" style="height: 50px;">
                        <div class="grid-6">
                            <strong>
                                <asp:Label ID="lblBrand" runat="server" Text="Brand"></asp:Label></strong><span class="required">*</span>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                    <td class="align-center tableStyle" style="height: 50px;">
                        <div class="grid-6">
                            <strong>
                                <asp:Label ID="lblProductName" runat="server" Text="Product Name"></asp:Label></strong><span class="required">*</span>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                    <td class="align-center tableStyle" style="height: 50px;">
                        <div class="grid-6">
                            <strong>
                                <asp:Label ID="lblDescription" runat="server" Text="Description"></asp:Label>
                            </strong>
                            <span class="required">*</span>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                    <td class="align-center tableStyle" style="height: 50px;">
                        <div class="grid-6">
                            <strong>
                                <asp:Label ID="lblSize" runat="server" Text="Size oz"></asp:Label>
                            </strong>
                            <span class="required">*</span>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                    <td class="align-center tableStyle" style="height: 50px">
                        <div class="grid-6">
                            <strong>
                                <asp:Label ID="lblSKU" runat="server" Text="SKU (Internal Numbering System)"></asp:Label>
                            </strong>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                    <td class="align-center tableStyle" style="height: 50px">
                        <div class="grid-6">
                            <strong>
                                <asp:Label ID="lblHeight" runat="server" Text="Height inches"></asp:Label>
                            </strong>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                    <td class="align-center tableStyle" style="height: 50px">
                        <div class="grid-6">
                            <strong>
                                <asp:Label ID="lblWidth" runat="server" Text="Width inches"></asp:Label>
                            </strong>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                    <td class="align-center tableStyle" style="height: 50px">
                        <div class="grid-6">
                            <strong>
                                <asp:Label ID="Depth" runat="server" Text="Depth inches"></asp:Label>
                            </strong>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                    <td class="align-center tableStyle" style="height: 50px">
                        <div class="grid-6">
                            <strong>
                                <asp:Label ID="lblGross" runat="server" Text="Gross Wt/oz/lb"></asp:Label>
                            </strong>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </HeaderTemplate>
        <ItemTemplate>
            <table id="tblProductList" runat="server" class="tableStyle" border="1">
                <tr>
                    <td class="align-center tableStyle">
                        <div class="grid-2">
                            <asp:Label ID="lblNumber" runat="server" CssClass="bold" Text='<%#Eval("LineNumber")%>'></asp:Label>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                    <td class="align-left tableStyle">
                        <div class="grid-6">
                            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rfvCompany" Display="Dynamic" ControlToValidate="txtCompany" runat="server" Text="Company required" ValidationGroup="addlocation" CssClass="error"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                            <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="regexCompany" Display="Dynamic" ControlToValidate="txtCompany" runat="server" Text="Enter a valid Company" ValidationGroup="addlocation" CssClass="error" ValidationExpression="(?:\s*[a-zA-Z0-9]{2,}\s*)*"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
                            <asp:TextBox ID="txtCompany" runat="server" Width="100%" Text='<%#Eval("Company")%>'></asp:TextBox>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                    <td class="align-left tableStyle">
                        <div class="grid-6">
                            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rfvBrand" Display="Dynamic" ControlToValidate="txtBrand" runat="server" Text="Brand required" ValidationGroup="addlocation" CssClass="error"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                            <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="regexBrand" Display="Dynamic" ControlToValidate="txtBrand" runat="server" Text="Enter a valid Brand" ValidationGroup="addlocation" CssClass="error" ValidationExpression="(?:\s*[a-zA-Z0-9]{2,}\s*)*"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
                            <asp:TextBox ID="txtBrand" runat="server" Width="100%" Text='<%#Eval("Brand")%>'></asp:TextBox>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                    <td class="align-left tableStyle">
                        <div class="grid-6">
                            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rfvProductName" Display="Dynamic" ControlToValidate="txtProductName" runat="server" Text="Product Name required" ValidationGroup="addlocation" CssClass="error"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                            <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="regexProductName" Display="Dynamic" ControlToValidate="txtProductName" runat="server" Text="Enter a valid Product Name" ValidationGroup="addlocation" CssClass="error" ValidationExpression="(?:\s*[a-zA-Z0-9]{2,}\s*)*"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
                            <asp:TextBox ID="txtProductName" runat="server" Width="100%" Text='<%#Eval("ProductName")%>'></asp:TextBox>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                    <td class="align-left tableStyle">
                        <div class="grid-6">
                            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rfvDescription" Display="Dynamic" ControlToValidate="txtDescription" runat="server" Text="Description required" ValidationGroup="addlocation" CssClass="error"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                            <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="regexDescription" Display="Dynamic" ControlToValidate="txtDescription" runat="server" Text="Enter a valid Description" ValidationGroup="addlocation" CssClass="error" ValidationExpression="(?:\s*[a-zA-Z0-9]{2,}\s*)*"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
                            <asp:TextBox ID="txtDescription" runat="server" Width="100%" Text='<%#Eval("Description")%>'></asp:TextBox>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                    <td class="align-left tableStyle">
                        <div class="grid-6">
                            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rfvSize" Display="Dynamic" ControlToValidate="txtSize" runat="server" Text="Size required" ValidationGroup="addlocation" CssClass="error"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                            <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="regexSize" Display="Dynamic" ControlToValidate="txtSize" runat="server" Text="Enter a valid Size" ValidationGroup="addlocation" CssClass="error" ValidationExpression="(?:\s*[a-zA-Z0-9]{2,}\s*)*"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
                            <asp:TextBox ID="txtSize" runat="server" Width="100%" Text='<%#Eval("Size")%>'></asp:TextBox>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                    <td class="align-left tableStyle">
                        <div class="grid-6">
                            <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="regexSKU" Display="Dynamic" ControlToValidate="txtSKU" runat="server" Text="Enter a valid SKU" ValidationGroup="addlocation" CssClass="error" ValidationExpression="(?:\s*[a-zA-Z0-9]{2,}\s*)*"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
                            <asp:TextBox ID="txtSKU" runat="server" Width="100%" Text='<%#Eval("SKU")%>'></asp:TextBox>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                    <td class="align-left tableStyle">
                        <div class="grid-6">
                            <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="regexHeight" Display="Dynamic" ControlToValidate="txtHeight" runat="server" CssClass="error" Text="Invalid Height" ValidationGroup="addlocation" ValidationExpression="^\d+(\.\d{1,2})?$"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
                            <asp:CustomValidator runat="server" ID="cvHeight"
                                CssClass="error"
                                Display="Dynamic"
                                ClientValidationFunction="ValidateHeight"
                                Text="Select Height" ValidationGroup="addlocation" />
                            <asp:TextBox ID="txtHeight" runat="server" Width="100%" MaxLength="6" Text='<%#Eval("Height")%>' onblur="CheckDecimalValue('txtHeight');" onkeypress="return AllowDecimal(event);" onkeyup="return CheckLengthText(this);"></asp:TextBox>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                    <td class="align-left tableStyle">
                        <div class="grid-6">
                            <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="regexWidth" Display="Dynamic" ControlToValidate="txtWidth" runat="server" CssClass="error" Text="Invalid Width" ValidationGroup="addlocation" ValidationExpression="^\d+(\.\d{1,2})?$"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
                            <asp:CustomValidator runat="server" ID="cvWidth"
                                CssClass="error"
                                Display="Dynamic"
                                ClientValidationFunction="ValidateWidth"
                                Text="Select Width" ValidationGroup="addlocation" />
                            <asp:TextBox ID="txtWidth" runat="server" Width="100%" MaxLength="6" Text='<%#Eval("Width")%>' onblur="CheckDecimalValue('txtWidth');" onkeypress="return AllowDecimal(event);" onkeyup="return CheckLengthText(this);"></asp:TextBox>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                    <td class="align-left tableStyle">
                        <div class="grid-6">
                            <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="regexDepth" Display="Dynamic" ControlToValidate="txtDepth" runat="server" CssClass="error" Text="Invalid Depth" ValidationGroup="addlocation" ValidationExpression="^\d+(\.\d{1,2})?$"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
                            <asp:CustomValidator runat="server" ID="cvDepth"
                                CssClass="error"
                                Display="Dynamic"
                                ClientValidationFunction="ValidateDepth"
                                Text="Select Depth" ValidationGroup="addlocation" />
                            <asp:TextBox ID="txtDepth" runat="server" Width="100%" MaxLength="6" Text='<%#Eval("Depth")%>' onblur="CheckDecimalValue('txtDepth');" onkeypress="return AllowDecimal(event);" onkeyup="return CheckLengthText(this);"></asp:TextBox>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                    <td class="align-left tableStyle">
                        <div class="grid-6">
                            <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="regexGross" Display="Dynamic" ControlToValidate="txtGross" runat="server" CssClass="error" Text="Invalid Gross" ValidationGroup="addlocation" ValidationExpression="^\d+(\.\d{1,2})?$"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
                            <asp:CustomValidator runat="server" ID="cvGross"
                                CssClass="error"
                                Display="Dynamic"
                                ClientValidationFunction="ValidateGross"
                                Text="Select Gross" ValidationGroup="addlocation" />
                            <asp:TextBox ID="txtGross" runat="server" Width="100%" MaxLength="6" Text='<%#Eval("Gross")%>' onblur="CheckDecimalValue('txtGross');" onkeypress="return AllowDecimal(event);" onkeyup="return CheckLengthText(this);"></asp:TextBox>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:Repeater>
```